# How to access the folders available in the server using IP address

Tags: c#-3.0

I have requirement to access the folder from a another machine based on the IP address. Can anyone suggest me to do with C#.

-Lokesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the IP as the servername in UNC path like `\\10.10.27.35\folder\subfolder\` (Don't forget to escape the \ in C#).

Comment: Hi thanks, i have used as you said when i try to create a sub directory i face an unauthorized exception. I have given full rights to the folder even though i get this exception. Any ideas?

Comment: @Lokesh: I tried it with StreamWriter myWriter = File.CreateText(@"\\10.10.27.35\folder\subfolder\text.txt"); It works. Can you save a file from editor to the UNC path with IP?

Comment: Sorry i did a mistake in my side. I dint provide permission for the shared folder. Now it is resolved Thanks.

Comment: @MatthiasAlleweldt:  what if we don't know what are the folders and sub-folders in that IP, and we want to get all the available shared folders in that given IP?